# Show Option Selected by Comparing Value in URL with SugarCRM/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, sugarcrm

I have two DropDown fields where I want one of their options to get selected dynamically. Since I'm using SugarCRM I can't directly write acondition in an option tag.

I want to get an option tag by its value in jQuery and add an attribute to it "selected=selected"

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom.js file and define it in custom/modules/{MODULE_NAME}/views/view.edit.php.

```
class Custom{MODULE_NAME}ViewEdit extends ViewEdit {
    function preDisplay(){
        parent::preDisplay();
        echo '<script language="javascript" src="custom/modules/{MODULE_NAME}/custom.js"> </script>'; 
    }
}
```

Then in custom.js do something like

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(setSelected);

function setSelected() {
    $('select#dropdown1').change(function() {
        $("select#dropdown2 option[value='Some Value']").attr('selected', 'selected');
        return false;
    });
}
```